# Regex to match a line containing certain words or symbol combinations

Tags: regex

Using Notepad++, I have this following code.

```
text "","text1"
waitinput
text "","text2"
waitinput
text "{user}","text3"
waittext

choice "option1","option2"

    text "","text4"
    waitinput
    text "{user}","text5"
    waitinput

    text "char","text6"
    waitinput
```

**I want to match all lines that have got `text "` or `choice "` in them.**

I'm using what I've learnt, but the result is always inconsistent.
some lines are being left out, lines that have an empty line above them don't get recognized...

**My attempts:**

Search: `^\s*text|^\s*choice`

Result:

```
    줄  1: text "","text1"
    줄  3: text "","text2"
    줄  5: text "{user}","text3"
    줄  7: 
    줄  9: 
    줄 12:   text "{user}","text5"
    줄 14:
```

Search: `^.*\b(text\s\"|choice\s\")\b.*$`

Result:

```
    줄  8: choice "option1","option2"
    줄 15:   text "char","text6"
```

and so on...
Nothing works. I need a code that flawlessly captures all lines in that sample above. Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to match all the lines that have a specific pattern in it you could do it something like this:

1. First you would want to match the beggining of a line with the `^` character.
2. Then you would want to match anything as long as it has your pattern in it. Like this: `.*(text "|choice ").*`
3. And finally you would match the end of the line with the `$` character.

So the final regex would look like this: `^.*(text "|choice ").*$`

Here is a runnable example with the test data you've provided:
https://regex101.com/r/uRB3mU/1

Comment: This seems to work! I'll have a closer look at it. Thank you so much

Comment: Neither the anchors nor the outer capture group are needed. If desired, `' "'` could be factored out of the inner capture group. Moreover, a non-capture group (if supported by the regex engine) would be preferred to the inner capture group, as a capture group may suggest to the reader that something is to be done with its contents, which is  not the case. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/O0PvTE/1)

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to write this but basically
the white space `\s` has to be pared down to allow only horizontal white space
`[^\S\r\n]` which won't span lines. Can also be written as `\h` on Perl, PCRE engines.

```
(?m)^[^\S\r\n]*(text|choice)[^\S\r\n]*"
```

https://regex101.com/r/VSlN0Z/1

Overview

```
(?m)                 # Multi-line mode
^ [^\S\r\n]*         # BOL , horizontal whitespace 
( text | choice )    # (1), text or choice
[^\S\r\n]* "         # horizontal whitespace , double quote
```

Comment: I just saw this now. Thank you very much for your input. I'll save that code as well!!